# Word or phrase for something that generates more hype than it can possibly live up to?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or phrase for something that generates more hype than it can possibly live up to?

I'm not thinking of something that was intentionally hyped, so *overhyped* isn't applicable. More like something mundane that just keeps getting postponed and discussed and wondered about until it builds into a bigger deal in everyone's mind than it could ever possibly be.

Comment: something like 'runaway expectations' ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

> [to snowball](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/snowballing)
>
> 1. To grow rapidly in significance, importance, or size: problems that snowballed by the hour.

Free Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

How about "meteoric rise"?

The phrase means "resembling a meteor's rise or trajectory,  in speed or in sudden and temporary brilliance"

For e.g.

Source: Merriam Webster

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like that *something* is ***overrated***.

Macmillan:

> **[overrated](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/overrated#overrated_3)** *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **not as** good or **important as some people believe**
>   a highly overrated
>   movie